# BCP escape \n in data

Tags: sql-server, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I'm using BCP to download data from SQL Server, using queryout option.

However, I notice that if the data content in any columns contain '\n', the content exported from BCP will be treated as newline.

For example, if the data in SQL Server is:

```
COLUMN_1 COLUMN_2
AAA NAME\nSURNAME
BBB NAMESURNAME
```

The exported file be like:

```
AAA NAME
SURNAME
BBB NAMESURNAME
```

Refer to BCP document, as I understand, the -c should not treat \n as newline.

> -c
>   Performs the operation using a character data type. This option does not prompt for each field; it uses char as the storage type, without prefixes and with \t (tab character) as the field separator and \r\n (newline character) as the row terminator. -c is not compatible with -w.

I'm not sure what I misunderstood.

Here is the command I use:

```
bcp "select [col_name] from [table_name] where [condition]" queryout test.dat -U[username] -P[password] -S[serverip.port] -c
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see that behaviour with `bcp "select 'hello\nworld'" queryout test.txt -S(local) -T -c`... `type test.txt` yields `hello\nworld` as expected - not a line break, but separate \ and n characters.

Comment: For reference, I was using `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\170\Tools\Binn\bcp.exe`

Comment: As your data sits in SQL Server, if you query it, do you actually see a "\n" in the data? Or do you mean that there is a "newline" character between the values in "column2" of your sample in the first record? This is an important distinction to make. If you have literally two bytes of "\" and "n" (this is less likely)... then this is more puzzling. But if you mean you have one byte "\n" the ascii newline character between you values, within the column then the answer is easy.

Comment: Hi @jamie, I still don't understand the different between '\n' and '\' and 'n'? As you mentioned that the way to solve this 2 cases are different (more puzzling one and easy one).

Comment: You have to first answer my prev question. Do you actually see a "\n" when you view the data from SSMS? If the data contains control characters as you say it does, then you would NOT see the data unless you viewed it with a quality text editor and you told it to show you control characters. These control characters NOT are printable. They do not exist to the human eye... "\n" is just a way to communicate a new line control character.  But if you do see the two characters "\" and "n" while viewing the data in a query result window in SSMS, then you have an odd issue.

Comment: it's been confusing because you said you have "\n" in your data, but below in Martin's answer you said you replaced \r\n (char(13) and char(10))... which is in your data? \n or \r\n?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. First I'm not using SSMS, due to some company policies, I'm not able to use many tools. The time I said about '\n' in my data is from using pyodbc (Python's lib) and query them out. Second, I was replacing the '\r' and '\n' separately not the '\r\n'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data contains newline or crlf control characters then those characters WILL, naturally, be included in the data that is copied out.

Are the control characters supposed to be there? If so, then leave them and they will be imported into whatever your destination is. Just because your text view shows a "broken" line, does not mean that SQL Server cannot ingest that line again and keep the control character tucked into the data (again, if those control characters belong there... i've seen plenty of cases where they would be).

If the newline character "\n" (or any control character for that matter) is NOT desired, then it's just a matter of doing as you commented in Martin's answer. Just clean the data either before you query it ("update") or during query (as you commented with "select/replace") or after you've copied the data out.

I've used "file cleaner" applications in the past to "clean" a file of unwanted characters (this can be an issue with long-lived data or data that has traversed various platforms or has been touched by humans!!! Yuck!).

Comment: I wonder if there is possible solution for the case that "\n" is desired, but the exported file will not be used by SQL Server? Also, as you mention the "file cleaner", I have tried to search for the tool, but only found the clean for OS.

Comment: "file cleaner" - proprietary app, every time. doubt you can find one. If the newline character is desired the destination does not matter (so long as you are not using native mode). If you want the newline character, just leave hte data as is and do not use "replace".

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your text includes the actual `\n` control character rather than simply the characters `\` and `n` next to each other?

Where this exists then your options are to either use native mode or change the row terminator to be something other than `\n` so that it recognises the correct pattern.

I'd suggest using native mode and test whether that re-imports the data correctly with the `\n` in place.

Comment: I'm not sure how to determine whether my text is the actual `\n` or not.

I'll try with native mode, and update again.

Comment: Hi Martin. After changing to native mode and test running again, I found that many characters are unreadable, except English ones. I'm not sure why the native mode gives this.

However, I tried replacing the `CR LF (CHAR(13), CHAR(10))` when `SELECT` in query. The result seems to be usable.

Comment: Native modes sends the data out in native SQL format. This is the format SQL Server used to store data in its own data files. It is used mainly to be more efficient (smaller file sizes) and can only be used when your source and destination are both SQL Server. You should not need to use native mode to address this though.

Comment: The fact that replacing the control characters in your `SELECT` statement works does indicate that the issue was with thosee characters in the output. Unless you need to be able to read the output files yourself (i.e. not just used for export/import) then use native mode as it will mean you don't have to check for the special characters in your text.   @jamie - why should native mode not be considered to address this?

Comment: Because native mode doesn't address it. The issue is just that there actually ARE control characters in the data. BCP isn't the one who is breaking the line. It is whatever reader the OP is using to view the file once bcp'd out. What should be confirmed by the OP is if the control characters are supposed to be there or not. They may very well be there because they are supposed to be in the data. Sending data out in native mode does nothing to address the control characters in the data... they will still be there when the native file is restored (can only restore to SQL btw).

Comment: The use of Native Mode just "hides" the \n characters in garbled native mode data. They are still there, you just can't view them easily in a native mode extract file.

Comment: Thank you so much Martin and jamie, now that I understand what the native mode should be used, I think it's not gonna fit my expectation, since I would like to export from SQL Server and read the data using Spark. Regarding the concern that the '\n' should be there or not, personally it doesn't really need to be there (just better if it can be), so I think I will have to consider the solutions and trade things off.